# What it makes a 3D model game-ready?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, game-engine, pbr

I've been up to Blender since mid 2016, started to work professionaly selling my 3D models since Jan, 2018... and now I'm used to hear the same questions from the customers: *"Are your models `game-ready`?"*

And I always reply: *"By the moment all my models published are not 100% optimized for games"*

I say this because I do use `PBR` materials, modelled mid-poly with `tris`, and now I'm learning to get my new models `rigged` and ready to animate. But I think something is missing.

The principal question is... ***what it takes to make a model game-ready?***

***do I have to use Blender Game Engine to achieve this?***
In college, they taught me how to use Cycles only, and I don't know if a model with mid-poly tris, PBR materials and properly rigged for animations makes it "game-ready" altough it was made entirely in Cycles engine.

***a "game-ready" model bought from a digital store, makes it ok for commercial licencing?*** this is a polemic question, but some customers ask this in some situations. For example: imagine that I make a 3D `game-ready` model of a Fender Stratocaster guitar, and sell it on internet via a third-parties 3D gallery. That model can make it into an actual published lucrative videogame using the brands and models I've made?

Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: It's a marketing term, like "lite," empty and unregulated.  But yes, reasonable vert count, textures (probably some kind of roughness map, metal map, albedo map, tangent space normal map) on a single in-bounds UV, rigged with standardized skeleton like Mecanim, all non-armature modifiers applied (because games probably don't have shrinkwrap or lattice deform), not going to give draw order issues from alpha.  BGE has nothing to do with any of that.  Licensing questions are a different matter entirely, and this isn't the right stack exchange for them.

Comment: **Game-ready** means that the model could be imported into a game engine like Unreal or Unity without much fuss and that it would render in real-time (>=60fps)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos only by its title, into the post I'm discussing a different situation.

Comment: just curious, what college was it that was teaching cycles?

Comment: @David it was at the UTN-INSPT (Universidad Tecnológica Nacional - Instituto Nacional Superior del Profesorado Técnico) in Argentina.